# Grails GORM events being called multiple times

Tags: grails

Just trying to implement a simple audit logging solution with Grails 2.0.2 and it looks like any of the domain class events are being called multiple times.  It is the same for the before* and after* events.

```
 def afterUpdate () {
        log.info "Updating..."
 }
```

I would have expected only 1 event to be triggered, so if this is being called many times by design how will I ensure only 1 audit entry is made?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just encountered the same issue myself recently.  There is a [JIRA open for this](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8237), which mentions it will be fixed in 2.0.4, looks like it fires the event for each datasource...meanwhile a JIRA user has kindly donated a simple workaround.

I tried the Auditable plugin but couldnt get that working how I want (maybe affected by the same issue)

Comment: @user1191386 How did you sort it out.